# How do I query for a Set<MyObject> using DBUtils?

Tags: java, apache-commons-dbutils

Looking over the [DBUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/dbutils/handlers/package-summary.html) API docs, I cannot see if it's possible to query for a Set.

Which implementation of ResultSetHandler i should use for query Set of objects?

Comment: Obviously that i can receive List and after convert this List to set but...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a default implementation for `Set`. You can create a generalized handler for `Set` as shown below.

```
public class SetHandler<T> implements ResultSetHandler<Set<T>> {
    private final RowProcessor rp = new BasicRowProcessor();
    private final Class<T> type;

    public SetHandler(Class<T> type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<T> handle(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
        Set<T> set = new HashSet<>();
        while (rs.next()) {
            set.add((T) this.rp.toBean(rs,type));
        }
        return set;
    }
}
```

One down side is that `toBean` method tries to find ResulSet Column-Bean Property mapping for every row in the ResultSet where as `toBeanList`method(used by BeanListHandler) find this mapping only once per list.

There is a `BeanMapHandler` which returns HashMap and it internally uses `toBean` method and hence I think for Sets/Maps we have to rely on `toBean` method or write a custom `RowProcessor`.